# Do i need to study quantum mechanics in order to learn quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, education, quantum-computer

Please tell me the relation between quantum computers and quantum mechanics. Also i want to know the topics common between the both. I searched this on the internet but didn't get clear answers.

Comment: Your question in the title is not the same as the question in the body; please write an appropriate title, or change the body. By the way, yes you need to study quantum mechanics and quantum information theory first.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Mr G.Smith, can you please describe the importance and weightage of quantum mechanics in quantum computing??

Comment: When you understand that -up is not equal to +down for a spin 1/2 system, you have enough QM.

Comment: This is like asking "*Do I need to study digital electronics to learn classical computing?*" Strictly saying you don't need, but it will help you a lot.

Comment: Yes. $\hspace{-0.001mm}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum computers use components whose behavior and performance depend on quantum mechanics.  If you want to understand the components, you will need to study quantum mechanics.

On the other hand,  quantum computing can be understood independently of the hardware on which it is done, just as in ordinary computing.  You can learn the necessary math without ever knowing it is the same math used to describe the detailed quantum mechanical processes going on inside the hardware.

That said, the better you understand how a computer works, the more expert you are likely to be at squeezing out maximum performance.  The same is going to be true of quantum computers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to build hardware, in which case yes, or do you mean to code algorithms, in which case probably not. Computing is about calculational algorithms, not understanding the physics. The one thing you do need to understand is the principle of superposition from quantum mechanics. The potential for quantum computing is that it is possible in principle to use superposition as a form of massive parallelism. That is the same calculation is carried out for many numerical data sets in a single calculation. If it is then possible to pick out particular numerical data sets by "collapsing the wave function", a huge amount of calculation can be reduced to a single process (this only works for particular algorithms, and of course someone must work out a way of applying it to the algorithm you are interested in).